# Laravel Storage::files() showing dotfiles when it shouldn't

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

I am trying to get a list of all the files in a folder using Laravel's `Storage::files('folder')` method, but it returns all the files, including .gitkeep

I want to find a way to exclude the dotFiles, and I know that the `Storage::files()` method has a secondary param that should do exactly that, because it is set by default, here:

```
public function files($directory, $hidden = false)
{
    return iterator_to_array(
        Finder::create()->files()->ignoreDotFiles(! $hidden)->in($directory)->depth(0)->sortByName(),
        false
    );
}
```

...but it doesn't seem to for for me!

Did anyone had this issue and can help a man out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By doing `Storage::files()`, you are not actually calling the method you mentioned.

`Storage::files()` calls `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::files()` instead. This confused me a lot before too.

What you want to do can actually be done using the `File` facade instead. This actually calls the method you mentioned.

```
File::files($path);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this!